# History of algebraic geometry over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview, finite-fields, weil-conjectures

My question is of historical nature: when did mathematicians start studying algebraic geometry *over finite fields* in a *systematic* way, and who were the main driving forces ?

Did it start with Weil (and the Weil conjectures) ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by "algebraic geometry" and "systemic". I think a case can be made for Gauss (and his famous "last entry" that motivated the Weil conjectures).

Comment: Prior to Weil there were Artin, Schmidt and others, although their study was mostly restricted to curves. See Peter Roquette's informative papers linked to in this relevant MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14627/the-work-of-e-artin-and-f-k-schmidt-on-what-are-now-called-the-weil-conject